# RGoogleAnalytics different browser page view as different row

Tags: r, google-analytics

We have used the RGoogleAnalytics  library from R. We have used the sample code google has provided for testing. So our init is like

```
query.list<-Init(start.date = "2015-01-01",
             end.date = "2015-07-28",
             dimensions = "ga:year,ga:month,ga:browser",
             metrics = "ga:pageviews",
             max.results = 10000,
             #sort = "ga:year",
             table.id = "ga:xxxxx")
ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)
ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, token)
```

After complete this and print the result we are getting the result like (format 1 below)

```
    **Year  Month   Browser              Pageviews**
1   2015    1       Amazon Silk             1
2   2015    1       Android Browser         4
3   2015    1       Chrome                  506
4   2015    1       Firefox                 157
5   2015    1       Internet Explorer       365
6   2015    1       Opera                   1
7   2015    1       Safari                  192
8   2015    1       Safari (in-app)         1
```

We are getting a format above. but instead i need to get the data like the different browser should be in different row like (format2 below)

```
**Year  Month   ie  firefox  chrome**

  2015   1     365   157       506
```

Can we able to print the values like in the format2 using the RGoogleAnalytics functions? Or do we have the any formatting method in R to convert the data from format1 listing to format2 listing

Also is there any option in RgoogleAnalytics to print 0 under a browser if there is no pageview under that browser on a particular month.

Comment: another option is using `library(tidyr); spread(ga.data, Browser, Pageviews)`

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform the data frame from **long** (all the browsers in one column) to **wide** (each browser in a new column). This can be easily done with the package reshape2. The function you need is dcast().

You can install the package with:

```
install.packages("reshape2")
```

and then load it with:

```
library(reshape2)
```

The usage of dcast() function is:

```
wideDataFrame <- dcast(longDataFrame, idVariableColumn1 + idVariableColumn2 ~ variableColumn, value.var="Name of column with the measurement values")
```

where

- wideDataFrame is your resulting data frame
- longDataFrame is the previous data frame (the one you have right now)
- idVariableColumn1 is the column that has to remain as a factor column
- idVariableColumn2 is another column to remain as a factor
- variableColumn is the colum you want to "open" in new columns
- and value.val = "name blablabla" is your column with values.

in your case

```
dataWide <- dcast(ga.data, Year + Month ~ Browser, value.var="Pageviews")
```

You can reshape *back* your data from wide to long (the opposite as we did here) with the function melt().